# Setting a bottom scroll indicator inset on a UIScrollView view has unexpected effect on horizontal scrollbar position

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

`UIScrollView` lets us set a `scrollIndicatorInset`. However, when setting a bottom inset for this value on a landscape iPhone with a `safeAreaInset` (i.e. a 'notch'), the horizontal position of the scrollbar is unexpectedly updated.

Here is a scroll view on an iPhone X with no changes to `scrollIndicatorInset` - note that the scrollbar on the right edge is horizontally flush with the edge of the screen.

[image]

Now I add one line of code:

`scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = 1`

The bottom edge of the scroll indicator is inset as expected. But the scrollbar is now also relocated horizontally to align with the safe area, rather than the screen edge.

[image]

**What is the cause of this horizontal inset and how can I prevent it?**

Setting the bottom scroll inset to anything other than 0 adds the additional margin, and setting it back to 0 removes it. The same thing applies when setting any of the scroll insets edges.

Some logging before and after setting the `scrollIndicatorInset` shows no change to the `safeAreaInset` nor the `layoutMargins` on the view, the scroll view, or the content view inside the scroll view.

One place this is a problem is when placing a text field inside a scroll view and adjusting the bottom inset to accommodate the keyboard. The scrollbar jumps around as the keyboard is presented and dismissed.

I am providing a small view controller below in case you want to try it out for yourself.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .white
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        let contentView = UIView()
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true

        // this causes the issue
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I've noticed that Apple's Mail app also has a similar issue - when composing an email in landscape orientation, the scroll bar moves in/out as the keyboard is displayed/dismissed. I don't expect this is expected behavior so perhaps an iOS bug. Would be nice to find a workaround.

Comment: It looks like changing the `.scrollIndicatorInsets` causes UIKit to calculate the scroll indicator frame relative to the **safe area**, even though you have your scroll view constrained to the view.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but as a workaround you can also set, in your case, the scroll view's right indicator inset to an appropriate negative distance, such as the parent view's right safe area inset.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    scrollView.verticalScrollIndicatorInsets.right = -self.view.safeAreaInsets.right
}
```

In iOS 13 and above, we should be using `horizontalScrollIndicatorInsets` and `verticalScrollIndicatorInsets` as `scrollIndicatorInsets` has been deprecated.

This isn't a perfect workaround, as you'll find the top and bottom insets also need adjusting. For instance, maybe you're trying to set the bottom inset to end halfway up the screen, and you're happy with that. But after these adjustments the top inset will now be zero by default, so you'll probably want to adjust that, too, or the scroll indicator will go all the way up into the rounded corner of the device.